# Updating a table in a .hyper file using Tableau hyperapi from Python has no effect

Tags: python, tableau-api

When I issue an update command against a .hyper file using the Tableau hyperapi package, it appears to complete successfully, but if I then query the same file I can see that the update has no effect.

Here's an example of the update command:

```
from tableauhyperapi import TableName, HyperProcess, Telemetry, Connection
with HyperProcess(telemetry=Telemetry.SEND_USAGE_DATA_TO_TABLEAU ) as hyper:
    with Connection(endpoint=hyper.endpoint, database=HYPER_FILE) as connection:   
            city = 'Adventure Bay'
            sql = f"UPDATE {TableName('Extract', 'Extract')} SET City = '{city}' where ZIPCODE in (11112, 11113) ;"
            print(connection.execute_command(sql))
```

Executing this seems fine. No errors reported. If I run the equivalent SQL in a select statement, I get rows returned, so I know those codes exist in the dataset.

But if I then run :

```
with HyperProcess(telemetry=Telemetry.SEND_USAGE_DATA_TO_TABLEAU ) as hyper:
    with Connection(endpoint=hyper.endpoint, database=HYPER_FILE) as connection:
        print(connection.execute_scalar_query(f'SELECT Count(1) FROM {TableName("Extract", 
"Extract")} where City = "Adventure Bay"))
```

I get 0, as if the update had never occurred. Likewise if I open the extract in Tableau, I can see the update has not has any effect

Am I missing a commit? Is some other step needed to save the results of the update to the hyper file?

Comment: Are you sure you're executing both these commands on the same hyper file? I would recommend running your `SELECT` query after you run your `UPDATE` command within the same `HyperProcess`.   So you'll be able to see if the changes have reflected right away.

Comment: Thanks @RadioActive. It's been six months now since I've worked on this. Next time I have any Tableau work on I'll try your suggestion and and report the result